USB A mechanical orientation?
This concerns a USB A socket on a PCB.
Is there a standard or preferred orientation of the polarization tab, either up or down?
The picture shows one with tab towards the top


The three-pronged logo of the USB represents the three times it takes to plug-in - try it one way, try it the other, try it back to the first way and now it works :-)

it does not matter which orientation you pick. once shipped, it will be in a permanent superposition of both orientations.

@dlatikay, there's no superposition; rather, a USB connector is a spin-1/2 particle.

Is any answer worthy an accept, maybe?

Yes. The receptacle tab goes on the top.
According to the USB specification, section 6.5.1 there are guidelines on orientation for USB-A receptacles:

6.5.1 USB Icon Location
The USB Icon is embossed, in a recessed area, on the topside of the USB plug. This provides easy user
recognition and facilitates alignment during the mating process. The USB Icon and Manufacturer’s logo
should not project beyond the overmold surface. The USB Icon is required, while the Manufacturer’s logo
is recommended, for both Series “A” and “B” plug assemblies. The USB Icon is also located adjacent to
each receptacle. Receptacles should be oriented to allow the Icon on the plug to be visible during the
mating process. Figure 6-6 illustrates the typical plug orientation.


source: https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-20-specification

To address the comment about this still not being defined for the relative position of the tab, Figure 6-6 shows how it is supposed to be, in relation to the USB logo. The USB logo should be visible while mating, and the USB logo is supposed to be opposite of the tab position.
Side note:
The orientation of the receptacle is of course dependent on how the product that holds the receptacle is supposed to be used when mating the connector. We can imagine a product where the connector is facing towards the ground — the tab is now neither up nor down, it's forward.
Since no info is given other than the image in the question, the reasonable assumption is that the product is oriented in a way such that the USB receptacle is to be facing the “operator”, horizontally. That would mean that the plug tab goes on the bottom, and receptacle tab goes on the top, according to the USB standard.

The question is about having the tab's relative position up or down. How does the excerpt in your answer define the tab's relative location i.e. top or bottom side? It mentions the "USB logo/icon" only.

@RohatKılıç It is defined. See the text in bold and the illustration in Figure 6-6. The logo goes on a specific side of the cable (the opposite of the tab), and the receptacle is oriented such that the logo goes up. Ergo - tab on bottom. As you also have observed from your devices.

Of course, one might be able to design a product using USB in such a way as to be able to state that there is no way to keep the usb plug up during mating - but that's not contradicting the intentions of the standard.

This answer seems to confuse the receptacle tab (what the question seems to be asking about) with the plug tab. The plug tab should be on the bottom if the logo is facing upwards, but that means that the receptacle tab is on the top. This is, in fact, how pretty much every laptop I’ve ever seen orients it, and also how most non-cable devices that include activity lights (flash drives, Wi-Fi/Bluetooth adapters, etc) assume the port is oriented.

@AustinHemmelgarn - In the side note which was a brief addendum responding to a comment it became refers to the plug tab, you're right. It's was also referring to an answer that was later deleted. I'll edit to clarify. Doesn't really change the core of the answer though, yes there's a standard and yes it defines the relative position of the the tab

The USB physical configuration is defective because the orientation of the receptacle is not clearly visible.  So how do you mate the plug with it, even if you know the orientation of the plug?  As engineers, we might make it fit by hitting it with a big hammer, but the cable prevents a direct blow.

Other answers have quoted the specification.
The problem is, it defines the preferred orientation of the plug and the designer needs to figure out the corresponding orientation of the socket. This requires 3-dimensional thinking, so it's clearly a mistake on the part of the specification writer, enabling the possibility of wrong orientations.
What it boils down to is:
The tab of the socket should be towards the side of the device facing the user: that is, towards the top with most normal handheld/desktop/free-standing devices. If your device is designed to be mounted on the ceiling or otherwise accessible primarily from below, then the socket's tab should be towards the bottom instead.

Likewise if your socket is vertically mounted in the top of the product, the tab should be at the front.

I absolutely address the orientation of the receptacle in my answer?

@MrGerber Yes, originally buried in the "side note". Your last edit makes it better, but the comments indicated a simpler answer was called for. Remember that the person making the question might be in a hurry, or not have English as their native language, or thinking about the relative orientations of the plug and socket makes their brains hurt, so the ideal answer would have been something short and to the point like "Tab of the socket towards the side facing the user. So usually towards the top".

I disagree. It's not the answerers business whether the questioner is in a hurry or doesn't have English as their main language. Answerers doesn't necessarily have English as their main language either (I don't). And if a concept as simple as thinking about "back vs front" makes their brain hurt, I don't think EE is for them. Either way, this is not a forum, it's a QA site and the answers on this site are supposed to have general value for readers in the future, and a simple yes/no answer without explanation is worthless in that regard.

That being said, I think we as answerers should be open to feedback, and I have now edited the conclusion to be in the start of my answer.

Universal Serial Bus Specification, Rev. 2.0 indirectly answers this question in chapter '6.5.1 USB Icon Location':

The USB Icon is embossed, in a recessed area, on the topside of the USB plug. This provides easy user
recognition and facilitates alignment during the mating process. The USB Icon and Manufacturer’s logo
should not project beyond the overmold surface. The USB Icon is required, while the Manufacturer’s logo
is recommended, for both Series “A” and “B” plug assemblies. The USB Icon is also located adjacent to
each receptacle. Receptacles should be oriented to allow the Icon on the plug to be visible during the
mating process. Figure 6-6 illustrates the typical plug orientation.


From the comments:

The question is about having the tab's relative position up or down. How does the excerpt in your answer define the tab's relative location i.e. top or bottom side? It mentions the "USB logo/icon" only.

The logo has to be visible when mating. So depending on how and where your device is mounted, the receptacle's tab must be on the top or bottom. In most of the cases (i.e. a device on your desk) the orientation as displayed in the question would be correct.

The question is about having the tab's relative position up or down. How does the excerpt in your answer define the tab's relative location i.e. top or bottom side? It mentions the "USB logo/icon" only.
